# Async Storage / Secure Store help for React Native

Tags: react-native

I'm doing a test app to learn react native, and I'm trying to use secure store (a bit like async storage) to store my individual goals and save them. So far it's working, however when I refresh the app only the last goal I entered gets loaded.

Where am I going wrong here? In my console log the full array is shown with both the old and the new ones I add, then I refresh and I only have one left.

```
const [goals, setGoals] = useState([])

const addGoal = async (goal) => {
    try{
        const goalJson = JSON.stringify({text: goal, id:`${Math.random()}`, todos:[], date: Date.now(), percentage:0})
        await SecureStore.setItemAsync("Goal", goalJson)
        load()
        }
        catch (err) {alert(err)}
}

const load = async() => {
    try {
     const goalValue = await SecureStore.getItemAsync("Goal")
     const parsed = JSON.parse(goalValue)
     if(goals !== null) {
        setGoals([...goals, parsed])
        console.log(goals)
    }
    }catch (err) {alert(err)}
  }


useEffect(()=> {
    load()
  },[])
```

Comment: `SecureStorage` seems to be an external dependency, so you should provide more detail like a GitHub project link or your package.json dependencies. However, anticipating that it works like the native `AsyncStorage`, every `setItemAsync` call with one goal overwrites the last one. It's not appended. You should set and get your entire array.

Comment: Ah okay, how would I set and get the entire array?

Comment: Same principle: for storage: append to state (`const newGoals = [...goals, newGoal]; setState(newGoals);` and persist the entire array (`setItemAsync('goals', JSON.stringify(newGoals))`); for loading, fetch the entire array `const goalsValue = await SecureStorage.getItemAsync('goals'); setGoals(JSON.parse(goalsValue));`

Comment: Thank you this worked, I understand now where I went wrong!

Answer (score 2):

`SecureStore` is like a key-value database, so currently you're always writing to the same key `Goal` and your `addGoal` function is erasing the previous value with `goalJson` content.

Instead, load once the goals from storage, then update the `goals` state when a new goal is added, and write them all to on storage each time `goals` value is updated.

This how effects works, by "reacting" to a change of value. This is just a little bit more complicated because of SecureStorage async functions.

Here is my (untested) improved code. I renamed the storage key from `Goal` to `Goals`.

```js
const [goals, setGoals] = useState([])
const [loaded, setLoaded] = useState(false)

useEffect(()=> {
  async function load() {
    try {
      const goalsValue = await SecureStore.getItemAsync("Goals")
      const goalsParsed = JSON.parse(goalsValue)

      if (goalsParsed !== null) {
        setGoals(goalsParsed)
      }

      setLoaded(true)
    } catch (err) { alert(err) }
  }

  load()

}, []) // load only when component mount


const addGoal = (text) => {
    const goal = { text, id:`${Math.random()}`, todos:[],
                   date: Date.now(), percentage:0 } 

    setGoals([...goals, goal])
})


useEffect(() => {
   async function saveGoals() {
     try {
        // save all goals to storage
        const goalsJson = JSON.stringify(goals)
        await SecureStore.setItemAsync("Goals", goalsJson)
     }
     catch (err) {alert(err)}
  }

  if (loaded) { // don't save before saved goals were loaded
    saveGoals();
  }
}, [goals, loaded]) // run the effect each time goals is changed
```

Comment: It didn't work but I think I see what you meant, I might need to implement some of this when I try updating the goal etc, I appreciate the answer, thank you!

Comment: OK, I fixed name of variable  `goals` in load() func which was already defined above